# Set Background to CCScene

Tags: background, cocos2d-iphone, ccscene

How could I set a background to the CCScene? What I want is when I zoom out or in my CCLayer the background size stay the same. Thanks in advance.

Comment: CCSprite added to the scene...

Answer (score 0):

I share the code

```
+(CCScene *) scene
```

{
    // 'scene' is an autorelease object.
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

```
// 'layer' is an autorelease object.
ActionLayer *layer = [ActionLayer node];

// add layer as a child to scene
[scene addChild: layer];

CCSprite *background =[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"sky.jpg"];
CCLayer *backgroundLayer = [CCLayer node];
[backgroundLayer addChild:background];

[scene addChild:layer.backgroundLayer z:-1];

// return the scene
return scene;
```

}